# I want a show command iptables -nL only ip to centos

Tags: linux, ip, iptables

I input command line

```
@IPTables -nL | grep "3306"
```

result ex

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1/28   0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3306

ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.2/28     0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3306
```

but I want the result

```
127.0.0.1/28 , 127.0.0.2/28
```

How should I do?

Comment: can't  be done it's result 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I found the answer   iptables -nL | grep "3306" |awk '{print $4","}'

Comment: awk  '/dpt:3306$/ { print $4 }'